# Combining results from multiple SELECT statements with different WHERE clauses into one query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that has a column with 15 distinct names (TotalName) in it two of those names would be flowOne and flowTwo. There is also a column that is a timestamp (t_stamp) and Value. Every time a new value is added to the table it is timestamped along with where it came from. I am trying to create a query that will give me columns for each of the 15 distinct names along with a total for the month and the month number. I have tried it for two of the names and they end up on separate rows. I would like to have it show up all on the same row for the month.

```
SELECT  YEAR(t_stamp) as 'Year', MONTH(t_stamp) as 'Month', sum(FlowTotals.FlowTotal) as 'flowOne', '' as 'flowTwo'
FROM DataBase.dbo.FlowTotals
WHERE FlowTotals.TotalName = 'flowOne'
    and year(t_stamp) = year(getDate())
Group By Year(t_stamp), Month(t_stamp)

UNION

SELECT  YEAR(t_stamp) as 'Year', MONTH(t_stamp) as 'Month', '' as 'flowOne', sum(FlowTotals.FlowTotal) as 'flowTwo'
FROM DataBase.dbo.FlowTotals
WHERE FlowTotals.TotalName = 'flowTwo'
    and year(t_stamp) = year(getDate())
Group By Year(t_stamp), Month(t_stamp)
```

Order by Month

This puts out

```
Year   Month   totalOne   totalTwo
2019     1     123456     0
2019     1     0          789123
2019     2     456789     0
2019     2     0          345678
```

I would like to have one row for month 1 one row for month 2 with all values on that row etc.

I know that part of the problem is I have '' as 'flowOne in my Select statements but that was the only way I could think of to separate into 2 different columns. The summing for each row is working as expected.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output. Looks like you don't need a UNION, use GROUP BY Year, Month with a PIVOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way and changing little on your query, would be to wrap your select as a cte and then use this cte to `group by` `year` and `month` and get the `sum(FlowOne)` and `sum(FlowTwo)`, like this (I replaced the empty strings with 0 so the sum works as they both will be numbers. The cast is to just prevent SQL from internally converting it to bit instead of int:

```
with cte as(
SELECT  YEAR(t_stamp) as 'Year', MONTH(t_stamp) as 'Month', sum(FlowTotals.FlowTotal) as 'flowOne', cast(0 as int) as 'flowTwo'
FROM DataBase.dbo.FlowTotals
WHERE FlowTotals.TotalName = 'flowOne'
    and year(t_stamp) = year(getDate())
Group By Year(t_stamp), Month(t_stamp)
UNION
SELECT  YEAR(t_stamp) as 'Year', MONTH(t_stamp) as 'Month', cast(0 as int) as 'flowOne', sum(FlowTotals.FlowTotal) as 'flowTwo'
FROM DataBase.dbo.FlowTotals
WHERE FlowTotals.TotalName = 'flowTwo'
  and year(t_stamp) = year(getDate())
Group By Year(t_stamp), Month(t_stamp)
)
select c.Year, c.Month, sum(c.FlowOne), sum(c.FlowTwo)
from cte as c
group by c.Year, c.Month
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `union` of your two queries, `join` them on `q1.year = q2.year and q1.month = q2.month`.